# trigger channel purge in tasks/message contains specific keyword

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

still working on my first python project(discord bot)

got finally my first task up running and its working flawless.

now i want to create a second task what is deleting the channel history every x hours.

my current "purge" event is just a command like this:

```
@bot.command(name='deleteme', help='testing command for dev use')
    async def purge(ctx, limit=1, member: discord.Member=None):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg = []
        try:
            limit = int(limit)
        except:
            return await ctx.send("Please pass in an integer as limit")
        if not member:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
            return await ctx.send(f"Purged {limit} messages", delete_after=3)
```

its working well when i use the "!deleteme" command, but everything i tried to put this in a tasks failed so far.

maybe u guys have some ideas how i could get it up to work.

Edit.

For everyone who has the same problem this is my solution which is working flawless.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=898)
async def __purge():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    if str(message_channel) == "YOURCHANNELNAME":
            await message_channel.purge(limit=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [discord tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Simply add `@tasks.loop(hours=2)` above your purge function to execute it every 2 hours. To start the loop, you must then call `purge.start()` in your Python script. This will execute the function and wait 2 hours before executing it again

Comment: hey first of all thanks for the answer. gonna get always a command error then.
"    purge.start()
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'start'"

Comment: My bad sorry, as can be seen on the site I linked, you can only use `@tasks.loop()` on functions and not command. So you should create a command `purge` that calls another function, for exemple `_purge` (its the common way to name it) that does the message deletion.

Then another function with the decorator that also calls `_purge`