# discord.py tasks not working 'Command' object has no attribute 'start

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

this is my task

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=2)
    async def purge(ctx, limit=1, member: discord.Member=None):
            message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
            await ctx.message.delete()
            msg = []
            try:
                limit = int(limit)
            except:
                return await ctx.send("Please pass in an integer as limit")
            if not member:
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
                return await ctx.send(f"Purged {limit} messages", delete_after=3)
    
    @purge.before_loop
    async def before():
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        print("Finished waiting")
```

output when i will start the bot is

```
 purge.start() AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'start
```

my other 3 discord.py tasks working without any problems, just this one is making me some trouble

Comment: See my new comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870558/trigger-channel-purge-in-tasks-message-contains-specific-keyword/66873230#66873230 for your previous question, this should work

Comment: tried your hint but still it will not work. first "missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'", then after couple hours more, no more error but also no functional purge task